# My two port valves let water through when closed

Tags: plumbing, valve

I have underfloor heating and the two port valves are letting water flow through even when in the off position. Recently the plumber has changed them three times and at one stage fitted both a two port valve and a solid valve and that still did not completely cut off the flow. The hot water is supplied from a central boiler that supplies all the apartments in the building. The pressure appears to be correct and the valves should be able to handle the pressure. Does any one have an idea what the problem might be. It's deigning me crazy

Comment: What makes you think water is flowing? What you describe doesn't make much sense.

Comment: One valve fail is common, two valves failing is possible.  6 or more valves failing is next to impossible.  Is it possible that the water has another path to bypass the valves?

Comment: Some valves have to have water flow in one direction to operate properly are they installed correctly? Is this a zone valve? Is it opening to protect the circulation pump? If so try removing one wire and see if it solves the leakage problem.

Comment: Is it possible that this is NOT plumbed the way you believe it is?

Comment: Yeah, that's gotta be it... there's a bypass somewhere to which you are unaware.

Comment: thanks for the comments - the valves have been plumbed in correctly. The plumber has now tried three different types of valves. He's as perplexed as me.

Comment: The water enters the flat separates into two pipes. One for hot water the other for underfloor heating. Each pipe has a two port valve which should stop the water flow when hot water or heating is not called for. There is a meter attached to the outflow pipe that records the flow of water. So I can see it is recording a small flow of water even when the valves are in the off position (and the outlet pipe is very hot. If I cut the flow using a lever valve (fitted before the two port valves) the meter reads zero flow. its very puzzling.